# Deploying App Insights availability test to UK South, but strangely the ARM says Russia

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-resource-manager

Whilst automating the deployment of an Application Insights availability monitoring resource, I noticed that oddly when saving UK South and exporting an ARM template from the portal, the name of the location appeared to be Russia instead.

I thought this was a mistake on my side, but after digging deep into the JavaScript and Network traffic I came across the following returned from:

https://management.azure.com/batch?api-version=2015-11-01

```
{
    "DisplayName": "North Central US",
    "Tag": "us-il-ch1-azr"
},
{
    "DisplayName": "West Europe",
    "Tag": "emea-nl-ams-azr"
},
{
    "DisplayName": "Southeast Asia",
    "Tag": "apac-sg-sin-azr"
},
{
    "DisplayName": "West US",
    "Tag": "us-ca-sjc-azr"
},
{
    "DisplayName": "South Central US",
    "Tag": "us-tx-sn1-azr"
},
{
    "DisplayName": "East US",
    "Tag": "us-va-ash-azr"
},
{
    "DisplayName": "East Asia",
    "Tag": "apac-hk-hkn-azr"
},
{
    "DisplayName": "North Europe",
    "Tag": "emea-gb-db3-azr"
},
{
    "DisplayName": "Japan East",
    "Tag": "apac-jp-kaw-edge"
},
{
    "DisplayName": "Australia East",
    "Tag": "emea-au-syd-edge"
},
{
    "DisplayName": "France Central (Formerly France South)",
    "Tag": "emea-ch-zrh-edge"
},
{
    "DisplayName": "France Central",
    "Tag": "emea-fr-pra-edge"
},
{
    "DisplayName": "UK South",
    "Tag": "emea-ru-msa-edge"
},
{
    "DisplayName": "UK West",
    "Tag": "emea-se-sto-edge"
},
{
    "DisplayName": "Brazil South",
    "Tag": "latam-br-gru-edge"
},
{
    "DisplayName": "Central US",
    "Tag": "us-fl-mia-edge"
}
```

When looking at the [quick start template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-dynamic-web-tests/README.md) it suggests this is as it seems, is Moscow.

Some of the infrastructure which is running the [availability monitoring is being deprecated](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/cloud-based-load-testing-service-eol/), and there's a discussion on the [Microsoft docs repo where an overhaul is mentioned](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/3793) to keep it running for a while longer. Is it possible that Moscow's name has been used as a workaround to represent the UK? Or is this a strange bug?

There doesn't seem to be a github to discuss the availability monitor, only things like the SDK, the ticket above is in the documentation repo, so I'm not sure the best forum to mention this. Notably there does seem to be [general confusion in the community whether it impacts Availability monitoring](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/31141), so it seems worthwhile discussing just in case it's a bug (or if  I'm being silly and missed something!).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I reached out directly to a friendly Programme Manager at Microsoft who kindly responded:

> ARM templates must use our internal location IDs, which, due to
>   historical reasons, do not match their actual location. This isn't
>   documented anywhere externally unfortunately. I'll take care of
>   updating the documentation, in the meantime here is a snippet from our
>   repository - Display Name is the actual location, and the Tag is our
>   internal location ID, which is also used in ARM.

```
DisplayName = "North Central US",
Tag = "us-il-ch1-azr"

DisplayName = "West Europe",
Tag = "emea-nl-ams-azr"

DisplayName = "Southeast Asia",
Tag = "apac-sg-sin-azr"

DisplayName = "West US",
Tag = "us-ca-sjc-azr"

DisplayName = "South Central US",
Tag = "us-tx-sn1-azr"

DisplayName = "East US",
Tag = "us-va-ash-azr"

DisplayName = "East Asia",
Tag = "apac-hk-hkn-azr"

DisplayName = "North Europe",
Tag = "emea-gb-db3-azr"

DisplayName = "Japan East",
Tag = "apac-jp-kaw-edge"

DisplayName = "Australia East",
Tag = "emea-au-syd-edge"

DisplayName = "France Central (Formerly France South)",
Tag = "emea-ch-zrh-edge"

DisplayName = "France Central",
Tag = "emea-fr-pra-edge"

DisplayName = "UK South",
Tag = "emea-ru-msa-edge"

DisplayName = "UK West",
Tag = "emea-se-sto-edge"

DisplayName = "Brazil South",
Tag = "latam-br-gru-edge"

DisplayName = "Central US",
Tag = "us-fl-mia-edge"
```

(I've abridged this from what looks like c# code)

The documentation is going to be updated in due course, so if someone comes across it before I do please feel free to add it as a comment.

Comment: This is correct. We have an item in our backlog to introduce new identifiers which will match locations (current tags will be supported indefinitely for backward compatibility reasons).

Comment: @ZakiMa how's the backlog item going? I too was confused when I saw the identifier name mention RU.